# can not scroll page by mouse after tmux split pane

Tags: linux, split, tmux

In tmux, when I split to multiple panes(vertically or horizontally):
1. I can't use mouse wheel to scroll screen output page.
2. I can't select and copy texts using mouse.

My problems do not exist if I work on a SINGLE pane.

I have `set-option -g mouse-select-pane on`, `setw -g mode-mouse on`, 
`set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'` in `.tmux.conf`.

So, what should I add to my `.tmux.conf` to solve these problems after tmux split?

Comment: You could always use hackery with Ctrl-B PageUp/PageDown.

Comment: I solved this using `bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "send-keys -M" "if -Ft= '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -M' 'copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"`